# Create 7 or 8 Character Hash From 15 Digit Number

Tags: hash

Sorry for the clickbait-y title, I wasn't sure how else to phrase my question.

I have a distinct set of records `A` with incremental 15 digit numbers. I need to convert those numbers to a distinct 7 (or 8, but not ideal) number. Then check to make sure we haven't already processed that original `A` record. (Think hashing or asymmetric encryption, but creating a smaller result, in length, rather than larger)

I've tried several different methods:

- Converting to hex (15 => 13 characters)
- Converting to base64 (15 => 12 characters)
- Generate an MD5 Hash from a new Guid, convert to base64, then substring the first 7 characters

Is this possible?

Comment: is this not why we have hashing?

Comment: @jbutler483 I don't understand the meaning behind your question. My problem is that hashing results keep resulting in results longer than my original value.